# DistUpgradeFetcherCore errors while upgrading 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04, do-release-upgrade

When I try to upgrade my 12.10 install to 13.04 via do-release-upgrade, I get the error:

```
File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 145, in <module>
fetcher.run_options += ["--mode=%s" % options.mode,
AttributeError: type object 'DistUpgradeFetcherCore' has no attribute 'run_options'
```

When upgrading from GTK, the update-manager quits after informing about the new upgrade.
This seems to be common as I've seen at least three threads on AskUbuntu about this error. Any help?

Comment: http://www.prestonlee.com/2013/04/26/ubuntu-12-10-to-13-04-server-upgrade-error/

Answer (score 0):

> **Source:** http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/debian/ubuntu-debian/attributeerror-type-object-distupgradefetchercore-has-no-attribute-run_options/

Seems running `sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get update` solves the problem. I noticed that while the problem was happening on my system, none of Canonical's or any other repos were enabled. Must be something wrong with the package management system...

Comment: Not working on my system. Ignore this...